# Help with separating fingers on model, absolute beginner

Tags: objects, edit-mode, vertices, transforms, edges

I am an complete beginner and I just need help with a simple task. I have a textured 3D model that I would like to use for VRChat (I know how to rig but not how to model) but the fingers are merged; I would like to seperate them if possible. I'm sure there's a way to add a vertex on an edge and either negate or pinch the vertices in a way to add a separation, but I just don't know how to do it.

[image: I would like it to follow the texture of the hand]
[image]
[image]

I know I seem like an utter novice, but I can just not wrap my head around all the shortcuts and tools; this would be a walk in the park for someone with experience. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a job for the Knife tool! (Default shortcut K).

Before you start though you may wish to convert to quads, which are typically easier to work with - select the whole mesh in edit mode (shortcut is A for select-all, usually) and still in edit mode use ctrl-j by default - although just typing quad in the command search function will return Tris to Quads as the second option.  Command search is very useful for when you don't know where to find a command.  F3 should bring it up, though I usually pick the interface mode where it's bound to Space, as I use it often.)

When in edit mode, press K, click where you want the cut to start (it will snap to edges and vertices, and you should probably start from an edge but don't necessarily need to be at any particular spot on that edge) then click at each new point you want.  [image: Knife tool pre-confirm]

It will cut new vertices into the mesh to form that geometry.  If you've pressed Z along the way it will cut all the way through, otherwise it just works on the visible side you're looking at.  [image: Knife tool after confirm]

Anyway, make some cuts up the length of the fingers, and you can start cleaning up all the other edges while keeping your new edges.  You will need to make new faces (possibly assigning textures) and probably even move some fingers around a bit to get it ready to rig.

Another useful tool is the Rip command (shortcut V in edit mode), which essentially takes one vertex (or set of vertices/edges/whatever) and rips it into multiple, with the ripped side depending on where your cursor is when you invoke it.  Have a play around with it, see if you need it.  [image: After rip command]

Together those would be the main two things I would use to split up that mesh.  After that, using F (make face) or alt-F (fill a bunch of faces - sometimes not always reliable but much faster when it works) to fill in the holes you've just made so that the fingers have actual side-faces where they used to be joined, and you should be most of the way there.

Comment: Thank you so much this is exactly what I needed to know, I've used blender in the past and I remember the knife tool now that you mention it. How would I go about assigning textures for the new faces in between the fingers? It just needs to be a flat skin tone, the same as the rest. Thanks!

Comment: No problem!  If the answer helped then you should accept it so the question is marked as answered and other people who have the same question will find it easier.

For texturing that's a different question really - I'd recommend finding a tutorial on UV mapping. That said, selecting the faces, going to the UV map workspace, selecting the texture, doing and unwrap on just those faces and then shrinking the result and moving it into any old skin tone area should probably work.  A tutorial will have more detail as to why and how, of course

Comment: I've started using the knife tool and it's going well, it is what I needed, but for some reason there are certain faces that I can't cut, it just misses them out and doesn't make the new edge. These are faces that are connected to a blue line, which I have looked up and could be something to do with it being marked as 'sharp'? But I'm not sure. Is there any way I can cut these faces or remove the sharp edge, and will that affect the texture that is already on the model? Thanks.

Comment: The sharp or edge bevel itself doesn't stop knife tool - the rest is getting beyond what should be handled via comments for a single stack exchange question.  You can remove sharp edges or bevel weights (both are blue, sharp edges are more on the cyan shade of blue) by going to edit mode, edge mode, select all, ctrl-E for edge specials menu and then clear sharp, then repeat for edge bevel weight and put in -1.  If you have a bevel modifier this will certainly change the mesh, you might want to apply it first but that will depend on what it's doing, you might want to just delete it instead.

Comment: I understand, what you said has fixed my issue and I should be good from here. Thanks for the help, you're a saint.